# Get rows from a table based on ID field and display as JSON/XML

Tags: grails

I have a grails application that has a users table and a results table, i need to be able to get all results from the results table that match the current CustomerID that is logged in and need to have the option to display them as JSON or XML.

When i try and use:

```
 Results.findByCustomerID
```

I don't get the option to pass a customer ID in like i do if i use:

```
Results.findByNumber()
```

My results table consists of a customer ID, Number, Result, Convert Service, Date, Time.

I'm doing this in a Results controller at the moment.

Any help?

Comment: Please add a code sample of your Results class and exact examples of finder invocations?

Comment: @xiimoss I have an object you cant see called `Object` when I do `Object.findByXyz()` it don't work like `Object.findByAbc`. If anyone asked you this what would your first question about it be ? would it not be well what does `Object` consist of ?. Think before you splurt a question. Will the wider audience understand what it is I am looking at

Comment: @AntonHlinisty Apologies, i fixed my issue not long after. My CustomerID property began with a capital letter!

Comment: @vahid Apologies, i fixed my issue not long after. My CustomerID property began with a capital letter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. My Domain class property began with a capital letter!